# UIView autoresizingMask problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

In iPad. I have a UIViewController with another UIview inside it, at the bottom.

```
 ____________
|            |
|            |
|   UIView   |
| Controller |
|            |
|            |
|         X  |
 ------------
```

The UIView is the X.

I define for it an autoresizingMask like this, on the viewDidLoad of the UIViewController

```
self.view.autoresizeSubviews = YES;

// xView creation

xView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

But this doesn't works, the xView rotates fine but out of the screen bounds on landscape.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the view to be at lower-right corner, it should have a flexible *left* and *top* margin.

```
 xView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: Still going outside thebounds. I don't know waht I'm doing wrong. When I try this on IB and rotates the view on IB, it works. But when I run the project, go out of the bounds. I'm sure I'm missing a property or something else :(

Comment: @Espuz: What's the autoresizing masks of all superviews of `xView`?

Comment: Thanks, Kenny, you got me the quid of the question. In my parent xView I don't have mask. Y put your mask on xView and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight on its parents and now it works well. Thank you again ^^