# How to adjust subviews position on screen when device changes its orientation?

Tags: ipad, orientation, uipickerview, autorotate, cgrectmake

I am adding pickerview on UItableviewcontroller when user taps on row. I am using following code to display it.
    [self.view.window addSubview:languagePicker];

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGSize pickerSize = CGSizeMake(768.0, 216.0);
    CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                  screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height,
                                  pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
    self.languagePicker.frame = startRect;

    // compute the end frame
    CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                   screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                                   pickerSize.width,
                                   pickerSize.height);


        self.languagePicker.frame=startRect;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
        [self.languagePicker setFrame:pickerRect];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It seem to work perfect when device is in portrait orientation but as soon as the orientation changes everything adjust itself except the added picker view.

I can get device orientation, remove old view and add new one according to orientation but I am not sure whether its a good way to do it or not. can I do it any other effective way ?

Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was stupid mistake, instead of putting that pickerview on view itself I just dragged it and put it in xib. Putting it in view itself solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should set :

```
self.languagePicker.autoresizingMask
```

This will help your view to automatically adjust according to the configured constraints.

Comment: Can you give me some more details or pointers to more on autoresizing?

Comment: visit: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html and look for autoresizingMask.

Comment: you might want to have a look at his post also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069388/uiview-autoresizingmask-problem

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I have gone through the links they says use automasking I put that code in there but it still not working ...